# Random image from folder

Tags: electron

How can I make possible that the app will load all of the images from the specific folder and then put in array and choose one image randomly? When chose one then pass to the fronted to show the image. How to do that too?

I am C# developer but not long time ago I found ElectronJS and this framework does everything easier so therefore I am moving to this framework.

I did in C# programming this way:

```
// basic settings.
            var ext = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };

            // we use same directory where program is.
            string targetDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\assets\\" + "images\\" + "animals\\";

            // Here we create our list of files
            // New list
            // Use GetFiles to getfilenames
            // Filter unwanted stuff away (like our program)
            if (Directory.Exists(targetDirectory))
            {
                Files = new List<string>
                (Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Where(s => ext.Any(es => s.EndsWith(es))));

                // Show first picture so we dont need wait 3 secs.
                ChangePicture();
            }
            else
            {
                panel5.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Resources.doggy);
            }
```

I don't know how to do in ElectronJS.
Thank you in advance the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I found the solution.
However I don't understand the people who are giving negative reputation for the opened question. If they are giving negative reputation then they could explain why.

Well anyway, I did fix this issue with this way:
I created images.js file and added this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function getRandImage() {
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./assets/images/animals/')
    /* now files is an Array of the name of the files in the folder and you can pick a random name inside of that array */
    let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
    console.log('../assets/images/animals/' + chosenFile);
    return '../assets/images/animals/' + chosenFile;
}

module.exports = { getRandImage }
```

I used console to see if the value is correct, otherwise others can delete that part.

Sending the data to the renderer process:

```
const { getRandImage } = require('./images');
   

 child.webContents.send('random-image', getRandImage());
```

I did put in the preload.js file the following (I used the starter pack electronjs github to start with something):

```
var { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('random-image', function (event, store) {
    document.getElementById("randompic").src = store;
    console.log(store);
  });
```

Same here, I did use console.log just for test the value is correct and I used to change the randompic ID related image src html to the randomly chosen image.
Hopefully I did helping those people who are newbie as me.